# PHP Regex basic rules - How to specify more than one thing

Tags: php, regex

I'm totally new at the Regex world and here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
[2 Chars] + [Any Amount of Digits] + [/] + [4 Digits]
```

For Instance:

```
AB001/2013
XY999537/2014
OB22/2010
```

Basically all I have is:

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b/', $var);
```

This ensures me that I'll have only 2 characters at the beginning, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the Regex understand that now I want to add another pattern from the 3rd character of the string and forward.

What I've tried:

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b[0-9]/', $var);
preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b\d/', $var);
preg_match('/(\b[A-Z]{2}\b)([0-9])/', $var);
```

And I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: For general regex reference, this site is about the best one out there: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should fit your needs :

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{2}\d+\/\d{4}\b/', $var);
/*
    \b           # word boundary
    [A-Z]{2}     # 2 uppercase letters
    \d+          # 1+ digits (\d = [0-9])
    \/           # a slash (escaped)
    \d{4}        # 4 digits
    \b           # word boundary
*/
```

[image]

Comment: Taking from `preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b\d/', $var);` does the `\b` mean that even though I asked for digits after it, it won't allow because the string has ended?

Comment: You're matching `[Word Start] + [2 Chars] + [Word End] + [1 Digit]` with this regex.

Comment: So why doesn't it approve AA0 or BB9 for instance?

Comment: Because of `\b`, which mean your word is ended (ie : you've got a space, a dot...). It work with "AA 0". `/\b[A-Z]{2}\d\b/` will match both "AA0" and "BB9".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
'#^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]*/[0-9]{4}$#'
```